# How should I format my essay?

Tags: formatting

I'm writing a 5,000 word essay, or dissertation, and I'm not very experienced.
I've been given no format to write in.

Originally, I was using Arial, with a size of 11-point and 1-inch line-spacing with justified alignment.

I’ve changed my font to Times New Roman, size 11, and 1.15 spacing. Should I left-align my text? Would doing so improve marks / readability?
I find the justified text looks much better...

Should I italicise my quotes? I find it to be much easier to tell an in-line quote from text, when it is italicised.

What’s *your* standard formatting for an essay.

Comment: Whatever format you choose, the most important thing is: be consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For legal submissions, Times 12 point, 1 inch margins all around, double-spaced, are required.  If your instructor cares, there should be instructions.  If your instructor doesn't care, then you get to create your own style, as long as it's not too far-out.